# Large-Scale Biospheres on Mars

Tags: planets, space-colonization, terraforming

I've been researching the idea of spreading out vast sheets of **aerogel across regions of Mars**. This would theoretically have the effect of both warming whatever land is under the sheet - thus melting the permafrost and forming lakes - as well as blocking UV rays.

A dome of such material over a large enough parcel of land would mean that **colonists wouldn't have to live underground**. As long as they remained under the aerogel, their biosphere would simulate being on Earth, albeit with only 38% of our gravity.

Question: What volume within the domed area would be needed to produce its own **weather system**, including rain and/or fog?  I'm envisioning an aerogel "roof" over the entirety of Galle Crater (215km diameter).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The issue with Mars is not UV radiation - That is blocked easily - but rather solar wind. UV rays on Earth are mostly blocked by the atmosphere. Solar wind is blocked by the magnetic field. Solar wind took a great part in dispersing Mars' atmosphere. It would find the low-density aerogel easy to penetrate. Plus, aerogel may be too brittle to handle micrometeorites and hold pressurized domes. I recommend you to watch Isaac Arthur's Youtube channel, episode "Domes on Mars" for more information.

Comment: Aerogel is a bizarre choice of materials for construction of pressurized domes. Basically none of its special properties are useful in such an application, and it has enormous disadvantages in mechanical properties, cost, and ease of manufacture and handling.

Comment: @ChristmasSnow Solar wind is mostly protons. A mm thick layer of anything blocks it. Problem is only that so we have secondary gamma radiation and that is already hard to block (requires tight metal layers, impossible in planet size and anyways it would shade sunshine).

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff I think, a power line around the Martian equator, pumped by constant circular current, could serve as the source of an artifical Martian magnetic field. Once I calculated it, the required wiring is huge but not impossibily huge (not much bigger as a huge gas or oil pipeline today). I see some chance that ultimately it could be make more economical to do that with superconductor and push the energy to its cooling (today nitrogen-cooled superconductors already exist, technology should be developed to make them planetary sized).

Comment: The solar wind is a non-issue, it's already blocked by the atmosphere. There is no need for a global magnetic field.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Right, that's how it is on Earth. Mars has less than 1% of Earth's atmospheric density and its magnetic field is almost dead, which may be an issue on Mars.

Comment: @GraySheep Generating a magnetic field out at the L1 point would likely be a more efficient use of resources that building a belt around the equator.

Comment: @ChristmasSnow less than 1% is still way more than enough to block the solar wind. It's not an issue.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Right! I did not think on that :-)

Comment: @MichaelRichardson I am curious but I think, maybe using electromagnetic effects, kinetical energy exchange and tidal-gravity effects, maybe even a stabilization around L1 would be possible. Beside that, simply shading could cool the superconductor to its working temperature. Maybe even a completely passive electromagnetic-gravitational-kinetical system would be possible, guaranting stability for hundreds of millions of years. And serving as a monolith after we killed ourselves.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff - Aerogel is commonly discussed in recent years as a means of terraforming /regions/ of Mars as opposed to the entire planet.  Not sure why you consider it "a bizarre choice of materials for construction of pressurized domes," or think that "none of its special properties are useful in such an application."

Comment: @ajderxsen there's one researcher who has proposed it being used in one paper. And it *is* a bizarre and terrible choice of materials for such an application. It is *entirely* unsuitable to such an application.

Answer (score 12):

In order to get proper "weather systems" the habitat would have to be truly vast and kilometers tall. Rain might be achievable in a much smaller habitat (hundreds of metres) and fog could probably occur in almost any sized open space given the right atmospheric conditions.

But weather systems would be that last thing to worry about. The 800kg gorilla in the room is the pressure inside the structure in fact at 1 atmosphere there would be 10 tonnes of force exerted on every square metre of roof (so a dozen gorilla's worth in force give or take). aerogel just won't stand it and would be blown apart in milliseconds. Any large structure on Mars would require a massive pressure vessel to contain it.

Comment: "almost any sized open space given the right atmospheric conditions".  100% true.  My 8' by 8' greenhouse gets quite a bit of fog in just a few hours if I forget to open the vents in the morning.

Comment: Yes like my bathroom!

Comment: When I refer to aerogel I'm only thinking of its insulating and shielding properties - not its need for reinforcement.  It would likely be placed within layers of tempered glass, plastic, or some other strong and translucent material, webbed with supporting beams.

Comment: You refer to the need for a theoretical dome to be "kilometers tall."  Galle Crater (I could use a different crater, or invent one) is approx. 2km from rim to bottom.  I've been referring to "domes" for simplicity's sake, but I suppose this wouldn't actually be a dome; more like a "roof" spread across the crater (obviously with support structures beneath) and relatively flat.

Comment: May be in the fullness of time they will do such a thing, but the "elephant" in the room is the pressure inside the "dome" which would be about one adult elephant's mass pushing out on every 6 square feet. I haven't done the calculations but there must be an awful lot of 6 square feet elephant pressure panels in a crater that is km's across.

Comment: Yeah, extra mass is actually *desirable* in this application, and aerogel's single most defining characteristic is its low density. You would use aerogel if you needed to minimize the mass of the dome, when you're more likely to be piling regolith on top of it to weigh it down. A thick enough layer of regolith that the insulating properties of aerogel are unnecessary.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff - Thanks for your input.  Certainly I lack expertise, which is why I'm here asking questions.  I'm asking on the basis of science articles I've read concerning aerogel usage on Mars, such as this one: https://www.discovermagazine.com/the-sciences/aerogels-could-be-used-to-build-terraforming-domes-on-mars

Comment: The article is interesting, but only refers to the insulating properties of aerogel, I strongly suspect that they are not robust enough to last long on the surface of Mars with dust and perchlorates and also contact with water with the potential for penetration by water vapor as well as freeze thaw action at some point.

Answer (score 6):

A lot smaller than you think.

May I present the [Goodyear Airdock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodyear_Airdock)

It is an airship hangar, 358m long x 99m wide x 64m high or ~2 million cubic meters.

Notably, in high humidity conditions, it is well known for the internal humidity condensing into a mist and raining *inside* the building.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  When you refer to "high humidity," how would that relate to the average temperature that humans would experience within?

Answer (score 3):

Martian atmosphere is only 0.6% of ours. That is the main problem. Mars is practically vacuum. Aerogel will fall down to the soil.

The density of the lightest aerogel is about the same as air, however as aerogel is essentially a sponge. Air goes into it and the density of the result will be roughly the sum of the density of the air and of the aerogel.

It is very likely not possible to have aerogel floating in the Martian atmosphere. I can not find a reference of an aerogel floating in the Earthian, 160 times denser atmosphere, on the reason above.

Even if it would work, the problem of the lack or air would still exist. You need to find a way to give them air. About a 0.1 atm of oxygen would be already enough. Mars has 0.006 atm of carbon dioxide.

Comment: The only use of aerogel I conceive in this setting is serving as an insulator lining the inside of the domes, which are made out of a much stronger material. Aerogel still lets in most of the light while being a good insulator and would not add too much weight to the structure. The domes, on the other hand, will carry most of the load comprising the weight, the internal pressure, radiation and micrometeorites.

Comment: You know you can add atmosphere via asteroids right? The question if not explicitly stating it implies an imported atmosphere.

Comment: How exactly do you "add atmosphere via asteroids"?

Comment: @Slarty there are proposals for terraforming mars that include adding nitrogen (which mars lacks, and a breathable atmosphere needs *something* inert as a buffer) from one or more outside sources. One such source is outer belt asteroids. That's only one of many steps though.

Comment: The question seems to imply several misunderstandings, so I could be wrong, but I don't think they were suggesting that the dome material would be buoyant and floating in the atmosphere of Mars, I think they were suggesting conventional pressurized domes, just constructed of aerogel for some reason.

Comment: @Slarty Not bad, but also the asteroids have no oxygen. Some of them has water, from which oxygen can be extracted. Much more simple: extracting the O2 from the Martian soil. About half of the mass of the Martian crust is O2. It has to be heated to about 1000C and catalized electrolysis can extract the O2 from that. Another problem: the required mass of oxygen is about 300 000 times of steel produced by the whole Earth in a year.

Comment: @Gray Sheep It doesn't sound remotely practical though that 300,000 x world steel production bit. 2.5 x 10^13 tonnes of gas in the current Martian atmosphere, going to need 1000x that at least.

Comment: @Slarty The process is not very different - you have the soil, inject some chemicals, heat to 1000C and electrolyze it. Of course it is much harder as steel production from ore but not 1000x more. Beside that, I think robotic manufacturing actually could do that. Factory produces robots, robots build robot factory, that build 1000000x more robots, and these build huge soil decomposer plants. On this way, the whole Mars could become a huge network of solar panel and oxygen extraction plants. Quick calculaton shows, about a hundred years is enough to get the needed oxygen. Maybe some decades.

Comment: @Slarty Hydrogen would be still hard. Melting the polar icecaps would help, but I am not sure if it would be ever enough. Very likely, only a very little free water will be only there, and a global water pipeline network will be needed to transfer it to everyone needeng that. But it will be a minuscule problem, compared to the oxygen extraction.

Comment: @Slarty To understand the Mars, imagine a cold Sahara without air. Living there, I think, living in an average, not very industrial Chinese city would become suddenly a nice option.

Comment: @ChristmasSnow adding it to the outside seems like the better idea to me. Insulators work much better if there is vaccum inside them.
If any insulator against convection heat loss is even necessary in the  thin mars atmosphere, maybe radiation heat loss is the dominating factor.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff, the aerogel would be reinforced.  As I said in another comment, there's already plenty of literature about aerogel used as insulation to terraform regions of Mars rather than the whole planet.

In any case, in retrospect I should've left out the aerogel bit, as that's superfluous to my real question, which is: What sort of weather would people inside a large habitation on Mars experience?  Or, put another way: What volume would a habitation have to have in order to produce its own weather system?

Answer (score 1):

Addressing some issues with the premise: aerogel is simply not a viable material for construction of pressurized domes, its tensile strength is quite low. It has impressive *compressive* strength, but it is so fragile that attempts to build actual structures with it are likely to result in a pile of aerogel shards and powder. Nobody builds anything out of aerogel, it's used as a non-structural material.

Also, UV protection is trivial, it's charged particles you need to worry about. For ionizing radiation capable of penetrating the atmosphere (mostly galactic cosmic rays), an aerogel dome may as well not be there. The radiation environment on the surface of Mars is already a little bit better than that on the ISS due to the shielding of the atmosphere, but permanent habitation will require more protection, and for that you want mass between you and the source, not the lightest material you can manufacture.

Additionally, with a full breathable atmosphere inside, there's 100 kN of outward force on every square meter of the dome. Ultra lightweight materials are the opposite of what you need here...you *want* a heavy dome, so its weight counters part of that pressure. A sufficiently thick layer of radiation shielding will help reduce the tensile requirements of the dome, and will also be a good thermal insulator. Aerogel just isn't advantageous here.

Comment: (a) The aerogel would be reinforced; I just didn't mention that. (b) There's already lots of literature on aerogel usage on Mars. Just google "aerogel + mars" and you'll immediately find some. (c) I shouldn't have mentioned the aerogel, since my concern here doesn't require a particular material in the dome; it concerns the /sheer volume/ of the habitat required to produce its own weather system.

Comment: The aerogel would not be reinforced. The dome would simply not be constructed of aerogel. Aerogel is not a structural material. You don't build domes out of it.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to take this (and similar) article, then: https://www.discovermagazine.com/the-sciences/aerogels-could-be-used-to-build-terraforming-domes-on-mars